# Set header with response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request, header

I'm trying to send a token from the client to fetch that on my **node.js** server.
then I want the response of the server to set this token in the **header** so that each further request from the client will send along with the token.

I'm using **vanilla javascript** for the front end and express on my backend

here's the fetch request:

```
data = {
        id: idToken
      };
      fetch("http://localhost:5000/check", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      }).then(response => {
        console.log(response);
      });
```

this is the **server** code:

```
app.post("/check", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.id);

  res.setHeader("token", req.body.id);
  res.redirect("/");
});
```

where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Headers are a generic way to send metadata with an HTTP message. They aren't a generic way to persist session data.

The tool designed to do what you want is a cookie.

Use [`res.cookie()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie) to set a cookie and the [cookie-parser](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-parser.html) middleware to read it back.

Consider using [cookie based sessions](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-session.html) instead.